# How to use eval() and compile() in python 3.7?

Tags: python, compilation, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to evaluate an expression in Python 3.7 that is read as string from a config file. The application is a Datalogger and the user shall be able to define his own conversion of the raw ADC value in the config file. Using `eval()` and `compile()` is handy, but is considered to be unsafe. I tried to use `ast.literal_eval()` but it does not work with Python 3.7, because it doesn't allows using operators like `+-*/`. Finally I came up with something like this:

```py
def convert(code, value):
    try: 
        return eval(code, {'__builtins__': {}}, {'value': value})
    except RecursionError as e:
        print(str(e))
    except NameError as e:
        print(str(e))

def compile_expression(expr):

    if '__' in expr:  # check for double underscore
        print('expression contains illegal characters')
        return None
    try:
        code = compile(expr, '<String>', 'eval')  # compile it for use with eval
    except SyntaxError as e:
        print('Invalid Syntax in expression. Using default value.')
        code = compile('value', '<String>', 'eval')       
    return code

expr = '(value-1)/0.005'         # string is read from a config file
code = compile_expression(expr)  # compile string 

if code is not None:
    t = convert(code, 1.1) # convert ADC value to temperature
    print(t)
```

At least I tried to make it as safe as I can. Does anyone have a suggestion how to do better or has a suitable alternative to `eval()` and `compile()`?

Comment: I read the similar qusetion above before. It explains a lot (very usefull) about `eval()` and `ast.literal_eval()` but finally it does not answer how to evaluate safely an expression containing operators in Python 3.7. The only solution I found is the code above, which I hope is not totally unsafe.